Numba SVML Enabled but "Can't Vectorize Due to Memory Conflicts" in Matrix-Vector Multiplication
I'm trying to optimize a simple matrix-vector multiplication function with Numba using SVML. However, when checking for SVML vectorization via python test.py | grep svml, LLVM reports it "Can't vectorize due to memory conflicts." I've verified that SVML is operational with code from this GitHub issue can successfully detect SVML instructions.
Here’s a minimal example reproducing the issue:
import numpy as np
import numba
import llvmlite.binding as llvm

llvm.set_option("", "--debug-only=loop-vectorize")

@numba.njit(parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def njit_generate_data(y, S, x, noise, n_observation, support, noise_level=0.1):
    x[support] = np.random.randn(len(support))
    for i in numba.prange(n_observation):
        y[i] = S[i] @ x + noise[i] * noise_level
    return S, x, y

i8 = numba.types.int8
f32 = numba.types.float32
b = numba.types.bool_
njit_generate_data.compile((f32[:], f32[:, :], f32[:], f32[:], i8, b[:], f32))

print(njit_generate_data.inspect_asm(njit_generate_data.signatures[0]))

LLVM error:
LV: Can't vectorize due to memory conflicts

System Information:

Python 3.10

Numba 0.60.0

numba -s | grep SVML output:
__SVML Information__
SVML state, config.USING_SVML                 : True
SVML library found and loaded                 : True
llvmlite using SVML patched LLVM              : True
SVML operational                              : True



What I've tried:

Removed parallelization prange
Manually expanded matrix multiplication (I thought this will work but it didn't)
Toggling parallel=True/False and fastmath=True/False
Adding ascontiguousarray for x, y and S according to this question

Am I missing anything regarding vectorization logic in Numba or LLVM that could cause this conflict?

I don't think Intel's SVML library is relevant here.  (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/cpp-compiler/developer-guide-reference/2021-8/intrinsics-for-short-vector-math-library-ops.html).  The operations you want to vectorize are are basic math ops (multiply and add) which are supported directly by hardware instructions like x86-64 AVX vmulps / vaddps or vfmadd...ps which LLVM can use directly (if it could auto-vectorize).  You shouldn't expect function calls to functions like __svml_hypot4.  (Unless it's trying to vectorize np.random.randn as well...)

S[i] @ x generally runs in parallel (assuming this is a real matrix-multiplication). You should not run it in parallel unless you set up the SVML to use 1 thread. Otherwise this will cause an oversubcription, that is, very bad performance on some machine (variable and unpredictable).

Which part is causing the problem? I think y = np.ascontiguousarray(y) itself also yield memory conflicts errors.

I understand that matrix multiplication was automatically vectorized, but why does manually unrolling the matrix multiplication still fail to enable SVML? Is it because these operations (multiply and add) are already directly supported by hardware instructions like AVX, so there's no need for SVML function calls?

LLVM said "Can't vectorize due to memory conflicts" so I'm not sure the matmul was auto-vectorized.  But if it was, it wouldn't be calling any SVML library functions, just using native machine instructions like vmulps / vaddps or vfmadd...ps.  Just like if it wasn't vectorized, it would be using the scalar versions vmulss / vaddss and maybe vfmadd...ss.

Are your inputs really non contiguous? This usually prevents SIMD vectorization. If not try njit_generate_data.compile((f32[::1], f32[:, ::1], f32[::1], f32[::1], i8, b[::1], f32)) for C-contigous arrays.
